# How to add div after parent container for wp_nav_menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function add_custom_nav( $items, $args ) {
if( $args->theme_location == 'menu-1' ) {
    return  "<div>I AM going CraZY</div>" . $items;
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_custom_nav', 10 , 2);
```

I looked up a lot of examples, but when I try calling it, there's no change.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Walker class to add elements after specific class.

Add Something like this in your `function.php`,

```
class Walker_Nav_Pointers extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $output .= sprintf( "\n<li><a href='%s'%s>%s</a></li>\n",
        $item->url,
        ( $item->object_id === get_the_ID() ) ? ' class="current"' : '',
        $item->title
    // Add your code to add your elements.
    );
}
}
```

then,

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array('walker' => new Walker_Nav_Pointers()););
?>
```

Check [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker). Hope this will help you. Thanks.